# Convert character vector to a single string with line breaks, save as an object in R

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to use R to take the contents of a character vector and create a single string with line breaks between the items. The ultimate goal is to import the text into an excel file, such that one cell contains all of the items, each one on a separate line.

```
TextVector <- c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
cat(paste(TextVector, collapse = '\n'))
```

This gives the output I want, but it's only printed...I cannot save it to an object. In the end, I want a csv file that will have the items contained in one cell with line breaks, that will appear like this:
Name1
Name2
Name3

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: `cat` outputs R objects to your console. Do: `new_text <- paste(TextVector, collapse = '\n')`. Then you can do: `write.table(x = new_text, file = 'somefile.csv', row.names = F, col.names=F)`. You should get something similar to your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the object into disk, you have several choices.

1. [save() or save.image()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html). The object or workspace will be saved as an .RData file. It can be loaded using load(), like load("/path/to/file.RData")
2. write to file, i.e, [write.table or write.csv](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html)
    can be csv, excel, tsv
3. if you want in xlsx format, you can use xlsx library

   library(xlsx)

   write.xlsx(mydata, "c:/mydata.xlsx")

Comment: also... use `row.names=F` to suppress the row numbers

Comment: Thanks very much...very helpful. The write.xlsx() command worked perfectly.